# Why is Heroku telling me it cannot find a package.json in my module when I do a heroku push

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, module

I created my own npm package from a fork of react-coverflow.  It appears to be working fine in my app locally using it this way: "npm install react-coverflow-mod" --save.

I can run my app using "run with debug (F5)" in VsCode and npm start on the client folder to start the React front end.

Then I do an npm run build on the client folder, and it works just fine.

When I do a heroku push it fails everytime with this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "../../react-coverflow-mod" 
as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

## 1. I know there is a package.json in the module because I can install it via "npm install react-coverflow-mod": https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-coverflow-mod

## 2.  The installed module has a package.json file in it

## 3. My github repo has a package.json in it:  https://github.com/leroyvaughan/react-coverflow

I'm not sure how I can fix this.  Do I need a package.json to go into the /Dist folder?  What is wrong here with Heroku.

Comment: Seams like somewhere in your code you have a relative path to `"../../react-coverflow-mod"`. If you do a search in your project can you find such thing ?

Comment: Yeah, I think I may have found the problem.  I was doing NPM install from a physical location on the hard drive and there was a package.json left in there somehow.  When I run 'npm install react-coverflow-mod' I get the same error.  I think perhaps I need to dig a bit deeper...

Comment: @sebastienbarbier: it's weird, I see this line in the debug log which is completely false because I can see the file in that directory.

verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\z\projects\\react-coverflow-mod\package.json'

Comment: File might be on your directy but ignored by git or not at the same position to heroku. Seams like en env issue, not easy to help you further.

Comment: @sebastianbarbier:  So it appears you were right with your initial comment.  I did a search but came up blank.  It was late so I was tired.  Found the problem today in my package.json file...but not in the npm package, in the deployed app...

   ` "react-coverflow-mod": "file:../../react-coverflow-mod", `

I'm not sure why it didn't come up in search results last night.  I think maybe I pasted it in with the surrounding quotes.

If you want to post the answer I'll give you credit for it.  Or I can do it myself and take the credits...mwuahahahahahaaaaaa!!!  You have 25 hours to respond...

Comment: App is running now:  https://top-ten-heroes.herokuapp.com/heroes/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like heroku try to install a package **from a relative path** instead of the published name. That would perfectly explain why you can run locally but not on a production environment.

Open your project and **search for the exact string** displayed in your log: `"../../react-coverflow-mod"` and you should be able to find quickly where it is.

If you run on a unix system (don't know about windows) you can do a search using grep:

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e '../../react-coverflow-mod'
```

Make sure it **includes your root folder** which contain `package.json`, and might we wise to **ignore** `node_modules` which is always massive.